# What is the purpose of this structure?

Tags: architecture

I wonder what the purpose is of the structure located above the entrance of the Charter Street Ragged School & Working Girls Home in Manchester:

[image: working girls entrance]

Is it purely ornamental? According to [this page](http://manchesterhistory.net/manchester/tours/tour16/area16page7.html) it was built in 1847.

Image from [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.4895872,-2.2367776,3a,55.8y,77.23h,89.33t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s1Q5yp5QUwCq6JvuAc_Wg9w!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

Comment: It looks to be ornamental ironwork, although I'm not sure what it is meant to represent. According to [this page](https://aroundmanchester.wordpress.com/category/general/), this entrance is on the corner of Dantzic Street, and was actually built as an extension to the earlier 1866 Ragged School (which had itself replaced the 1847 Ragged School) in 1898.

Comment: Isn't it simply holding up the corner of the building? The entrance cuts across the corner so the corner brickwork of the floors above needs to be supported in some manner. The design is probably more ornamental than is required but I'd say it was essentially structural.